# Understanding method inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Here is how the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) defines method inheritance:

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct
>   superinterfaces all abstract and default (§9.4) methods m for which
>   all of the following are true:
>
> - m is a member of the direct superclass or a direct superinterface, D,
>     of C.
> - m is public, protected, or declared with package access in the same
>     package as C.
> - No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature
>     (§8.4.2) of the signature of m.
> - **No concrete method inherited by C from its direct superclass has a**
>     **signature that is a subsignature of the signature of m.**
> - There exists no method m' that is a member of the direct superclass
>     or a direct superinterface, D', of C (m distinct from m', D distinct
>     from D'), such that m' from D' overrides the declaration of the method
>     m.

The 4th bullet is not clear to me. It's even not possible to declare both abstract and non-abstract methods in the same class. Couldn't you explain what the rule is actually about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C might inherit methods from both its direct super-class and from the interfaces it implements (in Java 8 it can even inherit default implementations from interfaces).

Suppose that `C` extends `B` and implements `I`.

B contains a method :

```
public void m (String s)
```

I contains a method (possibly with a default implementation):

```
public void m (String s)
```

The 4th bullet means that `C` will not inherit `I`'s `m` method, due to the existence of `B`'s `m` method. `C` will only inherit `B`'s `m` method.

If you look at the [similar section in the JLS for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> 8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding
>
> A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct
>   superinterfaces all abstract and non-abstract methods of the
>   superclass and superinterfaces that are public, protected, or declared
>   with default access in the same package as C, and are neither
>   overridden (§8.4.8.1) nor hidden (§8.4.8.2) by a declaration in the
>   class.
>
> Methods are overridden or hidden on a signature-by-signature basis.
>
> If, for example, a class declares two public methods with the same
>   name (§8.4.9), and a subclass overrides one of them, the subclass
>   still inherits the other method.
>
> If the method not inherited is declared in a class, or the method not
>   inherited is declared in an interface and the new declaration is
>   abstract, then the new declaration is said to override it.
>
> If the method not inherited is abstract and the new declaration is not
>   abstract, then the new declaration is said to implement it.

You'll notice there is no similar language, which makes sense if the bullet in question was added to address default interface methods introduced in Java 8.

Comment: What is the default implementation? All interfaces methods are public abstract, aren't they?

Comment: @St.Antario In Java 8 interfaces can supply default implementations to their methods.

Comment: Ok, I got that. So the interface's methods are still public abstarct, but can support default implementation. It's a little bit confused to me because I'm used to treating absract methods as the methods which doesn't contain any implementation.

Comment: @St.Antario If an interface has a default implementation to a method, this method is no longer abstract.

Comment: amen brother. Kudos for the Java 8 reference

Answer (score 0):

> The 4th bullet is not clear to me.

It means that you inherit all methods from the superclass which you don't overwrite by yourself.

> It's even not possible to declare both abstract and non-abstract methods in the same class.

What?

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public abstract void abstractMethod();

    public void concreteMethod() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I talked about methods with the same signature or when one has a subsignature of another.

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, what should be the use of inheriting an abstract method?